# Spritekit and Touch event (Coordinates seems flipped)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, sprite-kit

I have added an image on the SKScene using the following code -

```
char1 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"CH_designb_nerd.png"];
    char1.position = CGPointMake(225.0, 65.0);
    char1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [char1 setScale:0.35];
    [self addChild:char1];
```

Then I was trying to create a touch event on the image but CGRect of the image seems totally flipped on the other side of the screen. I have used the following code

```
(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(char1.frame, location)) {
        NSLog(@"yaaa!!");

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%.2f",location.x);
        NSLog(@"%.2f",char1.position.x);

    }

}
```

Im totally lost on this as the image is placed perfectly but the coordinates or the CGRect seems flipped. The image is placed on the bottom but only when i touch on top of the screen does it say touch occurred.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same thing, except in swift, I think its got something to do with trying to use `touch.locationInView(view)` inside a SKScene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this is due to getting the wrong click location. I would instead look at using the `SKNode` equivalent for hit testing. Something like this:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKSpriteNode *char1 = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"char1Name"];
if ([char1 containsPoint:location])
{
    ...
}
```

There might be some syntax errors here, typing from memory but you get the gist. Note: you would need to set the `name` property for `char1` to perform the lookup, or you could just enumerate `self.children` if there is only that node.

Comment: Slight change to @Matt's code:                                   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];                          if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"char1Name"]) {
         ...
    }

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

Nice example of spriteKit [Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: OMG...thank you so much..Damn this is one great website with srsly awesome users..